# Postfix - 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm trying to get postfix to deliver mail to gmail. I've followed this article on configuring it, but I still gives me an error:

```
relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.66.108]:587, delay=0.46, delays=0.05/0/0.37/0.04,
dsn=5.5.1, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.66.108] said: 530-5.5.1 
Authentication Required.
```

http://mhawthorne.net/posts/postfix-configuring-gmail-as-relay.html

What am I missing?

Here's my postfix config:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
biff = no
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter =
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 3
debug_peer_list = smtp.gmail.com
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
defer_transports =
delay_warning_time = 1h
disable_dns_lookups = no
disable_mime_output_conversion = no
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/html
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport =
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains =
masquerade_exceptions = root
message_size_limit = 0
message_strip_characters = \0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
myhostname = suse.home
mynetworks_style = subnet
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/README_FILES
relay_clientcerts =
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
relocated_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relocated
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/packages/postfix-doc/samples
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = maildrop
smtp_enforce_tls = no
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacerts
smtp_tls_cert_file =
smtp_tls_key_file =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_client_restrictions =
smtpd_helo_required = no
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/access
smtpd_tls_CAfile =
smtpd_tls_CApath =
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file =
smtpd_tls_key_file =
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
smtpd_use_tls = no
strict_8bitmime = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: why do you have `smtp_enforce_tls = no`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need to go to Google's [unlock page](https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha), as the new IP address trying to send the mail is raising security concerns.

Once you have unlocked via the browser, the script will be able to send.

Comment: that link is no longer available from Google.